# Keep new lines in CDATA when unmarshalling xml in java

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

TL;DR; I need to keep new lines in CDATA when I unmarshal an xml file to an object.

I have an xml file (for example):

```
<xmlTag>
       <![CDATA[<someXml>This content
                     is formatted</someXml>]]    
</xmlTag>
```

I'm transforming this into a namespaced Object with this code (Filter and SAXSource is only because the input xml doesn't have a namespace, but the generated Class T does):

```
public static <T> T transformFileToObject(File file, Class<T> clazz, XMLFilter filter) throws .. {
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
    XMLReader reader = XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader();
    if (filter != null) { 
        filter.setParent(reader);
    }

    InputSource is = new InputSource(new FileInputStream(input));
    SAXSource source = new SAXSource(filter, is);

    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
    return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(source);
}
```

My problem is that when I call this, my xml is parsed just fine. I get an object that could look like this:

```
class XmlTag {
    private String someXml = "This content is formatted";
}
```

And therein lies the problem. The String is NOT formatted. I've seen this been discussed a lot in a marshalling point of view, but I haven't seen anything about this the other way.

I've tried setting encoding to keep linebreaks, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm thinking that I could make a hack that swaps out linebreaks from \r\n to SOME_RESERVED_STRING and swap it back later in the property, but in my use case, there can be several instances of someXml, which means I have to do ugly String operations.

TL;DR; I need to keep new lines in CDATA when I unmarshal an xml file to an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a problem with the defined xsd, as it was defined as an xsd:normalizedString, not an xsd:string.

So basically anything I did just got nullified by that adapter. It works out of the box in CDATA.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#sec-line-ends it appears that different new line characters are uniformed to the standard new line character.
Is there any reason you need to use `\r\n` instead of just `\n`?

Comment: Not really, no - but my files are downloaded from a third party, and I don't want to manipulate them (I will if I find a solution around it though) edit: I did a "read xml as string, then transform it from string to object" operation, so I can manipulate the string if needed. Replaced \r\n with \n, but no effect.